# Adding multiple solutions to one repository (GitHub)

Tags: c#, git, github, visual-studio-2013

I'm still getting used to the whole concept of Git and everything, so sorry if its a silly question.
Looked around the web but can't seem to get any answers.

I have to make an application for which I need to have the application project itself (UI and app logic) and a portable class library.
For this, I've created two separate VS solutions.

Now I need to put both these solutions (preferable from VS) into one repository.
I've added one of the solutions already (using Team Explorer), but can't seem to add the other one to the same repository.

Am I doing the right thing or should I create the class library and app in the same VS solution itself?
What am I supposed to do?